# How to use $_POST in php to get the value of selected content in select tag

Tags: javascript, php

The first thing is that I created a select button using javascript, here is the code in :

```
var select = "<form action='' method='post'><select id='line' name='choice'>";

for (var j = 0; j < jsondata.length; j++) {
    select += '<option>' + jsondata[j]['productLine'] + '</option>'
};
select += "</select></form>";

document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = select; // put the button in html tag
```

Now I'm trying to get the value of the selected content each time, and then pass the value to the SQL in PHP, here are lines of codes of PHP

```
$p = $_POST['choice'];
echo $p;

$sql_p = "SELECT productCode,productName
FROM products
WHERE productLine = '".$p."'";
```

But I got the Undefined index: choice. And no value is received.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you putting HTML into JS for? Use Ajax for this.

Comment: Where is your submit button?  Is it outside of the `<form></form>`?

Comment: Does there have to be a submit button with using select tag?

Comment: @Liu  If you don't have one, how exactly are you submitting the form?  You should show that in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry. Just started learning PHP. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add a value to the option tag, so that the selected option value will be received in the $_POST.

```
var jsondata = [];
jsondata.push({"productLine":"Test"});
jsondata.push({"productLine":"Test1"});
var select = "<form action='' method='post'><select id='line' name='choice'>";
for (var j = 0; j < jsondata.length; j++) {
    select += '<option value="'+jsondata[j]['productLine'] +'">' + jsondata[j]['productLine'] + '</option>'
};
select += "</select></form>";
document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = select; // put the button in html tag
```